# Notify hook is throwing an integer is required error .Why?

Tags: python-2.7, mercurial, hook

I am using the notCi hook to notify my CI server.This is not giving me any issue with

hg = version 2.2.1
OS = Linux
Python 2.6.6

But giving me an issue with

hg = version 4.6.1
os = Linux
Python 2.7.5

it looks me there is change in hg 4.6.1 version.Any idea?

```
 22 def notci(ui, repo, node=None, **kwargs):
 23     """Notify the continuous integration server about pushed changesets.
 24     """
 25
 26     (isRemote, uid) = __parse_url(kwargs['url'])
 27     if not isRemote:
 28         return False
 29
 30     ui.status(_('Not CI'))
 31     rel_repo = repo.root[len('/test/repo/'):]
 32     print rel_repo
 33     for rev in xrange(repo[node], len(repo)):
 34         cset = repo[rev]
 35         print cset
 36         curl = '/usr/bin/curl -d repo=/%s -d user=%s -d changeset=%s -d branch=%s http://jenkins.com'
 37         curl = curl % (rel_repo, uid, cset, cset.branch())
 38         print curl
 39         ui.status(_("  %s pushed changeset %s\n" % (uid, cset)))
 40         #ui.status(_("%s\n" % curl))
 41         if subprocess.call(curl, shell=True):
 42             ui.status(_("Could not notify service\n"))
 43             return False
```

> > Error : line 33, in notifyci
> >     for rev in xrange(repo[node], len(repo)):  TypeError: an integer is
> >     required

I explored this more and found if I remove repo[node] from line number 33 then it moved to next but doesn't give me the right changeset.It looks the issue is with repo[node]

Comment: It's likely related to the changes in this series https://phab.mercurial-scm.org/D3197. You can help yourself with the `changectxdeprecwarn` function defined here: https://phab.mercurial-scm.org/D3197, line 380. Do you know which kind of object if `node` in `notifyci`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `repo[node]` can no longer be implicitly converted to integer. You need to explicitly get the revision number user `repo[node].rev()`

line 33 become:

```
     for rev in xrange(repo[node].rev(), len(repo)):
```

(disclaimer: I've not tested the code)

Comment: Thanks for answering this.I did also in the same way.           c = repo[node]
 for rev in xrange(c.rev(), len(repo)):